# How to maintain the background-color of the cell of a Bootstrap table-bordered when printing it(without important?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When table and table-bordered Bootstrap classes are used, how can we maintain the background-color of the cell when I print it? If you render the code below, click with the right button and select “Print…”, the color will disappear, even with the “!important” declaration. I believed this would be the highest CSS rule priority (!important on the style attribute), but it doesn’t seem to be the case. I tried a css class on a separate .css file as well, but it didn’t work either.

If I use “-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact” it will work using “!important” in the HTML tag. But is there a way to achieve the same results using CSS classes? Otherwise I will have to spread “!important” everywhere.

```
<html>
<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<br>

<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
                <td style='background-color: #ff0000 !important; color: #0000ff;'>Testing</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to set media=all on the link to stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

```
.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td {
background-color: green;
}
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

`medial=all` is one option another one you can use

`@media print` media query in your css file.